# Android LinearLayout with two ListViews

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to create a LinearLayout with two Listviews and can not see the second Listview.
In the example you will see that I would like to have an image, then a title (for the first Listview), then the ListView.  This should be followed by another title (for the second Listview) then the second ListView.  I want both ListViews to scroll and not effect each other.  Basically the idea is that a user can scroll through two different lists.  This has been working nicely with just one ListView and just today I noticed I have a long forgotten Relativelayout (RelativeLayout01) that seems to being doing nothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bkgrnd"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/test_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="30sp"
    android:paddingTop="30sp"
    android:src="@drawable/title" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="716sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ title1_head"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/ title1_head"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="12pt" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView_Menu"
        android:layout_width="716sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/textured" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title2_head"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/title2_head"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="12pt" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout03"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView1_Menu"
        android:layout_width="716sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/textured" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Actually, all of your relative layouts are doing nothing. You should remove them. Nested layout are bad for performance

Comment: The relative layouts that wrap first list view use android:layout_height="fill_parent", which eat up all screen and push all the rest elements behind it out of you screen. yes, easy solution is remove all relative layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appears to be happening is the first `ListView` is doing exactly as you told it and filling all available space and you're making the Layout more complicated. Use only 1 `LinearLayout` and use `android:weight="0"` for the header and non `ListView` views and `android:weight="1"` for your `ListView` views.  The weight will help you to control the height of `ListView` views.

If you want more granular control over each group of header and list wrap them in their own `LinearLayout` and try not to put a weight on the contents of this layout as it can affect performance.

Comment: all looked nice in potrait but not so good in landscape - went back to having one listview.  Thanks for the replys, I learned something but it ended up not being a good implementation for the user experience.

Answer (score 1):

This will have the two listviews side by side

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/test_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="30sp"
                android:paddingTop="30sp"
                android:src="@drawable/title" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title1_head"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60sp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="title1"
                        android:text="@string/title1_head"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12pt" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/ListView_Menu"
                android:layout_width="716sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
                    android:listSelector="@drawable/textured" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title2_head"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60sp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/title2_head"
                android:text="title2"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12pt" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/ListView1_Menu"
                android:layout_width="716sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
                    android:listSelector="@drawable/textured" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is still fairly ugly due to nested layouts. RelativeLayout may prove to be better. I can re-work this later but for now this will accomplish what you need